# Cannot set secure cookie in firefox 90.02 or 78.13.0esr, using tornado 6.1.0.0, python 3.73. Ok in chrome, edge etc

Tags: firefox, cookies, tornado

I have a local web server application (self signed certificate) that has stopped working in firefox (both windows and linux). It does not set any secure cookies. The following test code only sets cookie test2. The application behaves fine in chrome and edge with all cookies being set and has previously worked in firefox. My searches have not turned up anything, other than an issue marked as fixed [bugzilla 1618113](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1618113). Setting an exception for the ip address to allow cookies does not fix this.

Further checking on an older platform shows that the secure cookie is set correctly using tornado 3.2.2.0 and python 3.4.2.

```
     settings_ssl = {
         "cookie_secret": cookie_secret,
         "login_url": "/login",
         "static_path": "/var/www",
         "template_path": "/home/pi/py/web",
         "default_handler_class": ErrorHandler,
         "default_handler_args": dict(status_code=404),
     }

     self.set_secure_cookie("test1","cookie_secure") 
     self.set_cookie("test2","cookie_insecure")
```

Any help gratefully received.

Images added in edit:
[Cookies set in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8TDU.png)
[Cookies et in Chrome by same code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4ziV.png)

Comment: In my option,the method ,`set_secure_cookie`  method just will make the brower or the server,checking time and others,not encryption the cookie.I always  do encryption before set cookie if it is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. set_secure_cookie certainly encrypts the value in Chrome.

Comment: From the document `https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html?highlight=set_secure_cookie#tornado.web.RequestHandler.set_secure_cookie`, it shows:`Signs and timestamps a cookie so it cannot be forged.` Try  more document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to bigpangl. I can no longer see the comments we both posted between Aug 12 and yesterday, however checking the POST data led me to discover that, on firefox, the expiry time of the cookie appears to be set based on the time of the server. It appears to be calculated based on the time of the browsing computer when using chrome.

My local server time was 61 days in the past, so the default expires_days value of 30 in tornado meant that the cookie expired in the past and was not stored on firefox.